# how to identify a transaction with IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

First of all sorry about my english,
I have a small problem with the IPN PayPal notification system. After a payment is done on my website, Paypal send to me a IPN message in order to confirm the transaction. In my website I need to do some stuff, including setting a variable which indicates the order can be send. But in the case two payments with the same amount are done at the same moment, how can I distinguish them? The user's mail is not enough because the mail I have can be diferent of the paypal user's mail...

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think using the custom filed I can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction is identified by the `txn_id` field. In the case of a `Reversal` or `Cancel_reversal,` the original transaction it refers to is given by the `parent_txn_id` field.

I don't see what 'with the same amount' has to do with it.